# App crashes on rotate during webservice call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing an Android App on Xamarin.
During the async call to a webservice (about 1 - 2 seconds) if i rotate the screen it crashes.

Is there a way to let the webservice call to continue its call even if i rotate the screen?

It is necessary to rotate the screen because i have to read a barcode on landscape mode, and when i return to Portrait mode it fails.

I do the call in this way:

```
myItem = await Item.GetItem(itemId);
```

and this is the OnCreate method that has been called every time i rotate the screen

```
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
```

Comment: What's the crash about ?? Add the crash logs .

Comment: Hi ADM, the app stops unexpectedly, without Exceptions!